# They seem not to have learned grammar x They seem haven't learned grammar

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question related to these two sentences, when talking about the present perfect, which one should be used?

> They seem not to have learned grammar
>
> They seem haven't learned grammar
>
> They seem to haven't learned grammar

Are they correct?

Comment: Only your first version is valid. Other grammatical alternatives include *They **seem to have not** learned grammar, They **don't seem to have** learned grammar, **It seems they have not** learned grammar,...* The first of those is only idiomatically acceptable (though still relatively uncommon) in the *uncontracted* form (native speakers would never use the contraction as per your third version, but I don't think that's a matter of strict grammar//syntax - it's just a matter of what people actually *say*).

Comment: "what people actually say" = grammar  :)

Comment: @TRomano and what do people actually say? I was almost sure that I could use They don't seem to have learned grammar or They seem not to have learned grammar, but I was unsure wheter this sentence might contain any grammar mistake, or not being spoken currently

Comment: @FumbleFingers  saying **They don't seem to have learned grammar** does not change the sense of the question?

Comment: @Davyd: Perhaps I've got a limited imagination, but I really can't think of more than one possible meaning for any/all of these alternatives. Even including ***seems*** (or alternatives such as ***appears*** or ***looks like***) wouldn't *actually* change the meaning in most contexts, since the speaker would rarely be consciously choosing to use that particular [hedge/mitigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) specifically to allow for the possibility that "appearances can be deceptive".

Comment: @DavydDiniz: It depends on the person.  An educated person: *Mr Bond seems not to have learned his lesson.*  **seems not** is a tad formal, not very, just a tad. The average man in the street: *Bond doesn't seem to have learned his lesson*.  **doesn't seem** is normal register.

Comment: thank, both of you, I wasn't sure about using seem + present perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentences is correct

> They seem not to have learned grammar.

Your second sentence needs to be restated from

> They seem haven't learned grammar

to

> *It* seems *they*  haven't learned grammar.

Your third sentence is almost correct, the contraction needs to be expanded because of the "to"

> They seem *to have not* learned grammar.